# I wanted to change my computation device, but there is no dropdown menu to change it

Tags: cycles-render-engine, system

The title already says it all.

[image]

How can I change the device?
EDIT: Yes, I have a (Nvidia) graphics card and CUDA installed

I've got a GeForce GTX 960M with updated drivers

Comment: Could you tell us more about your system? What OS are you using? What version of Blender, 2.79?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Blender 2.79. I followed this question (or rather the answer) and installed nvidia-modprob additionally to nvidia-cuda-toolkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to installing the drivers and Cuda, I had to choose the NVidia card as the card used for rendering (hybrid card), by running`sudo prime-select nvidia` and log off and in again, afterwards it works.
This is now really off-topic.

Comment: Doesn't seem off-topic to me..